# Virtual member function definitions

Tags: c++, oop

Hopefully a straightforward question, I don't know what this is actually called, or even if it's a reasonable solution to my problem. Essentially I want to have a class which defines all the functions I want to use, but have different definitions of those functions depending on what 'type' of that class I want;

baseClass.h

```
#include "entityclass.h"

class baseClass {
    private:
        EntityClass EntityType1; // How do I choose
        EntityClass EntityType2; // which definitions to use?
};
```

EntityClass.h

```
class EntityClass {
    private:
        int someVariables;

    public:
        EntityClass();

        virtual ~EntityClass();

        virtual void foo();
};
```

EntityType1.cpp

```
#include "EntityClass.h"

EntityClass::EntityClass()
{
    //stuff1
}

EntityClass::~EntityClass()
{
    //destructiveStuff1
}

void foo()
{
    //definition1
}
```

EntityType2.cpp

```
#include "EntityClass.h"

EntityClass::EntityClass()
{
    //stuff2
}

EntityClass::~EntityClass()
{
    //destructiveStuff2
}

void foo()
{
    //definition2
}
```

Is this a reasonable solution to my problem, and if so, how do I specify in my base class which definitions I want to use to create my object? I'm sure this has been answered before, I just have no idea what to search for to find the answer.

EDIT - oops, didn't intend to include a second virtual constructor, it was supposed to be a destructor!

Comment: I'm not sure the solution you suggest here is reasonable. Can you tell us more on what you are trying to model.

Comment: looks like this could help - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_interfaces.htm

Comment: I'm trying to make a game with different entities, but where all entities need the same functions, but with different definitions - they all need to be rendered, they all need to be animated, etc. Some entities may be controlled by user input, and another may control itself, for example.

Comment: `virtual EntityClass();` There's nothing like a virtual constructor in c++!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
class baseClass
{
virtual void foo() = 0; // Pure virtual function: must be implemented when 
}

class EntityClassA : baseClass
{
void foo() { ... }
}
class EntityClassB : baseClass
{
void foo() { ... }
}
```

Now you define the class you want when you call it:

```
baseClass *myObj = new EntityClassA();
myObj->foo(); // Calls foo() in EntityClassA
myObj = new EntityClassB();
myObj->foo(); // Calls foo() in EntityClassB
```

Note that if you have destructor it also should be declared as `virtual` so that when `baseClass` is deleted it calls the destructors for the subclasses as well.

Comment: Shouldn't myObj by a pointer? baseClass * myObj = new EntityClassA();

Comment: Missing virtual destructor too. And you should avoid to do memory leak that way...

Comment: Thanks for spotting that peops. @Jarod42, absolutely right - that's why I didn't include one (for simplicity). i.e. *if* there's a destructor it must be virtual. I'll add that to the post.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you cannot define a virtual constructor, i.e., `virtual EntityClass()`.

The reason for this is simple: each instance contains a pointer to the virtual-function table of its class. This pointer is assigned **only** when the constructor is called (based on the **explicit** type of the instance).

The whole point behind virtual functions, is that you don't need to specify the exact type of the instance which "calls" them. Instead, this type is "determined" **only** during runtime (using the object's pointer to the V-table), **after** the instance is created. So the creation of the instance itself (i.e., the constructor) **cannot** be done through the **virtual-function mechanism**.

In contrast, the destructor of the base-class **should** typically be declared as `virtual`, in order to ensure that the destructor of any sub-class instance is called when the instance is "terminated".

As to your question, all you need to do is **inherit** two different classes from the base-class.

Here is one simple way of doing it:

```
class baseClass
{
protected:
    baseClass();          // implement it in the source file
    virtual ~baseClass(); // implement it in the source file
    virtual void foo()=0; // or implement it in the source file if it has any meaning in the base class
};

class EntityClass1 : public baseClass
{
public:
    EntityClass1();  // implement it in the source file
    ~EntityClass1(); // implement it in the source file
    void foo();      // implement it in the source file
};

class EntityClass2 : public baseClass
{
public:
    EntityClass2();  // implement it in the source file
    ~EntityClass2(); // implement it in the source file
    void foo();      // implement it in the source file
};
```

Comment: Sorry, typo, it was meant to be a virtual destructor!

Comment: OK, so I guess that the entire description of the virtual-function mechanism is a little redundant in this case (unless it gives you a better perception in general). In any case, the rest of the answer is still relevant to your question.

Comment: No, it wasn't redundant, I still found it useful!